# How to allocate a UTF8 string on the stack/heap?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe8

How can I allocate a UTF8 String on a stack/heap? Here is an example which uses a static array to allocate it. However the array is full of "?" in the debugger. Do I need to factor in codepage also while allocating?

```
program Project1;

procedure Main;
var
  Stack: Array[0..20] of AnsiChar;
  Heap: PAnsiChar;
begin
  Stack := '漢語漢語漢語漢語';

  GetMem(Heap, 8 * SizeOf(AnsiChar));
  Move(PAnsiChar('漢語漢語漢語漢語')^, Heap^, 8 * SizeOf(AnsiChar));
end;

begin
  Main;
end.
```

On the other hand this works fine.

```
program Project1;

procedure Main;
var
  S: UTF8String;
begin
  S := '漢語漢語漢語漢語';
end;

begin
  Main;
end.
```

Comment: consider to use `WideChar`

Comment: It would really help to have more context here. In the real use case, what are you going to do with the UTF-8 encoded bytes? Why can't you use `TEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes`? Why does it matter whether the bytes live on the stack or the heap? I'm sure you have reasons, but it will help us know know more of your thinking.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I am trying to avoid heap as much as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>You cannot persuade the compiler to produce a UTF-8 encoded constant. It will provide either ANSI or UTF-16, but not UTF-8. You'll have to handle the encoding yourself.</strike>

That could look like this:

```
procedure Main;
const
  utf8string: PAnsiChar =
    #$E6#$BC#$A2#$E8#$AA#$9E#$E6#$BC#$A2#$E8#$AA#$9E +
    #$E6#$BC#$A2#$E8#$AA#$9E#$E6#$BC#$A2#$E8#$AA#$9E +
    #$00;
var
  Stack: array [0..24] of AnsiChar;
begin
  Move(Pointer(utf8string)^, Stack, SizeOf(Stack));
end;
```

Actually, it turns out I was wrong. You can persuade the compiler to UTF-8 encode constants. Like this:

```
procedure Main;
const
  utf8str: UTF8String = '漢語漢語漢語漢語';
var
  Stack: array [0..24] of AnsiChar;
begin
  Assert(Length(utf8str) + 1 = Length(Stack));
  Move(Pointer(utf8str)^, Stack, SizeOf(Stack));
end;
```

Note that your array was too short for the text, once it has been UTF-8 encoded.

You already know how to allocate memory on the heap, so I don't need to explain that.

Comment: Yeah, it turns out that the compiler can be persuaded to UTF-8 encode constants

Comment: You can also cast it :)

Comment: @user246408 I wonder if this doesn't create one of those hidden variables in the Assembly?

Comment: @user15124 What to you mean by "this" in that comment?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I mean by casting the constant. `UTF8String( '漢語漢語漢語漢語')`

Comment: OK, but I'm not quite sure how you are going to work that cast into the code that copies into a local char array.

Comment: I suppose `StrLCopy(PAnsiChar(@Stack),PAnsiChar(utf8Str),SizeOf(stack));` should work as well instead of `Move()`.

Comment: @LURD It doesn't. :)
@DavidHeffernan To cast an individual char this is possible `Stack[0] := UTF8String('語')[1];`

Comment: That's pretty useless though, since 語 requires three bytes to encode in UTF-8

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Just an example... with a preprocessor you wouldn't even notice it.

Comment: Looks like I was mistaken - Delphi 2009 is capable of hardcoding UTF8 string literals. I had some problem with hardcoding non-UTF16 literals in Delphi 2009 years ago but it appeared it is not here.

Comment: The code in my answer does exactly that! The compiler spits out a constant 8 bit string encoded as UTF-8.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Does that actually allocate a hidden variable behind the scenes somewhere? Seems like `PAnsiChar(UTF8String(''));` is better.

Comment: `PAnsiChar(UTF8String(''))` is the empty string. When did you start wanting the empty string? I'm very confused by these questions. Look at the code. The only code is a call to `Move`. In other words, nothing happens other than a memory copy. That's it.